# Getting started with Mock server and Grunt

Tags: javascript, gruntjs, mocking

I've read the documentation on http://www.mock-server.com/.
But after few hours of effort spent on following this getting started
I still cannot get mockserver working.

Can somebody please specify the exact steps 
or point me on what is wrong?

Gruntfile:

```
 var configObj = {
    connect: {
        all: {
            options:{
                port: 9000,
                hostname: "0.0.0.0"
            }
        }
    },
   start_mockserver: {
    start: {
        options: {
            serverPort: 8080,
            proxyPort: 1090
        }
    }
},
stop_mockserver: {
    stop: {

    }
  }
}
```

In my index.html

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/jamesdbloom/mockserver/6a2fb42cb7933d0d68e7d595785a9b0536450825/mockserver-client-javascript/src/main/javascript/mockServerClient.js"></script>  



<script>    
     mockServerClient("localhost", 9000).mockSimpleResponse('/somePath', {   name: 'value' }, 203);
      </script>
```

I don't understand how mockserver and grunt connect work togeter on different ports

The error I receive in browser on 9000 is 
PUT http://localhost:9000/expectation 405 (Method Not Allowed)

Answer (score 1):

I am going through the same difficulties. I believe that mockserver is probably one of the worst when it comes to documentation. They will go and explain so many new concepts without telling you in which file the configurations should be placed. I have yet to see a configuration file name in their documentation. I am currently investigating this because I need to use it for a project. I will report here if I find anything useful. I am using Nodejs but the concept should be the same.

Edit:

I have discovered that you need to setup your mock-server expectation as part of the request using the mockserver-client. So you send to the server the specs describing the way you want it to respond to you, then you call the server in a way that will match the expectation that you have submitted, etc.

Unfortunately this didn't worked for me. I started getting errors that I couldn't find any explanation for in the documentation. That's when I have decided to find an alternative.

The alternative I found is far more simple and flexible than Mock-Server. It's called **canned**. It works by mapping a folder structure with the incoming request. If a specific file is found in the matching folder, then its content will be used to produce the corresponding response and its extension will dictate the content type. Give it a try. You might love it. It's at https://www.npmjs.com/package/canned

I hope this will help.

Answer (score 0):

Gruntfile did not work for me. I was able to start it using node and js.